# install/import Pytorch on mac osx / python 3.7

Tags: pip, pytorch, python-3.7, parlai

I have torch all installed in a virtual env, but python cannot seem to import it.

```
(venv) ➜  ParlAI git:(master) pip install torch
Requirement already satisfied: torch in ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from torch) (1.18.0)

(venv) ➜  ParlAI git:(master) python --version
Python 3.7.6

(venv) ➜  ParlAI git:(master) python
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  3 2020, 07:48:25)
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'

>>> ^D


(venv) ➜  ParlAI git:(master) cat venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/version.py
__version__ = '1.3.1'
debug = False
cuda = None
git_version = 'ee77ccbb6da4e2efd83673e798acf7081bc03564'
```

followed everything from here:
https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

I'm trying out some of the ParlAI samples, eg

https://parl.ai/projects/dialogue_safety/

```
(venv) ➜  ParlAI git:(master) python examples/display_data.py -t dialogue_safety:adversarial --round 1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples/display_data.py", line 22, in <module>
    opt = parser.parse_args()
  File "/Volumes/slab/trainingData/ParlAI/parlai/core/params.py", line 1072, in parse_args
    self.add_extra_args(args)
  File "/Volumes/slab/trainingData/ParlAI/parlai/core/params.py", line 889, in add_extra_args
    self.add_task_args(task)
  File "/Volumes/slab/trainingData/ParlAI/parlai/core/params.py", line 812, in add_task_args
    agent = load_teacher_module(t)
  File "/Volumes/slab/trainingData/ParlAI/parlai/core/loader.py", line 217, in load_teacher_module
    task_module = load_task_module(taskname)
  File "/Volumes/slab/trainingData/ParlAI/parlai/core/loader.py", line 187, in load_task_module
    task_module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Volumes/slab/trainingData/ParlAI/parlai/tasks/dialogue_safety/agents.py", line 12, in <module>
    from parlai.core.teachers import FixedDialogTeacher
  File "/Volumes/slab/trainingData/ParlAI/parlai/core/teachers.py", line 51, in <module>
    import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

Any suggestions what else I can try with this environment? I don't really want to use anaconda, prefer a bit more control of the system.